# issue with rails terms of service validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, simple-form

I am experiencing an issue with validating our terms of service checkbox using devise and simple form.

User Model

```
validates_acceptance_of :terms, :allow_nil => false, :message => :terms_not_accepted, :on => :create
```

Registration View

```
= f.label :terms, "I agree to the #{link_to 'Terms of Service', "http://britevid.com/terms_of_service",:remote => true}.".html_safe, {class: "checkbox inline"}
= f.check_box :terms 
= f.button :submit, 'Sign up', :class => 'btn btn-success'
```

Application Controller

```
def update_sanitized_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :company, :phone_number, :website, :content_description, :address, :city, :state, :zip_code, :country, :paypal_email, :time_zone, :email, :current_password, :password, :password_confirmation, :terms)}
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) {|u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :company, :phone_number, :website, :content_description, :address, :city, :state, :zip_code, :country, :paypal_email, :time_zone, :email, :current_password, :password, :password_confirmation)}
end
```

---

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-21 07:19:24 -0500
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"jeff", "last_name"=>"smith", "email"=>"jeffsmith@lol.com", "company"=>"test", "phone_number"=>"453234562", "website"=>"", "content_description"=>"test", "address"=>"1st ave", "city"=>"big city", "state"=>"California", "country"=>"United States", "zip_code"=>"095610", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "terms"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'jeffsmith@lol.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.haml within layouts/pages (46.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/shared/_external_header.html.haml (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 157ms (Views: 67.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

Comment: What is the issue? The log doesn't tell us anything. Provide the complete log, if there are errors then share that. Be verbose on what the issue is.

Comment: @KirtiThorat updated the original post

Comment: Did you get any error on the page? Why the user record was not created?

Comment: This is the error message. Please review the problems below:

Comment: You don't see a list of problems? Make sure that you have ` <%= devise_error_messages! %>` in the `devise/registrations/new.html.erb` so you actually see the list of error messages in the view. Which would tell you as to why the record was not saved.

Comment: Ok. I added the =devise_error_messages! and now I see 1 error prohibited this user from being saved:
Terms Please accept the terms of service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have setup a validation on `terms`

```
validates_acceptance_of :terms, :allow_nil => false, :message => :terms_not_accepted, :on => :create
```

So, its mandatory to check the `terms` checkbox while creating a new `User`. If you don't select the checkbox then your validation fails and you get the error. And ofcourse user record doesn't get saved.

As per the server log, while submitting the form you didn't select the `terms` checkbox as `"terms"=>"0"`(in params hash).

Make sure that you select the terms before submitting the form.